# Push notification can not get on mobile using laravel

Tags: firebase, laravel-5.7

I am trying to send push notification to a mobile device using the following function but it can not send. I am checking through firebase, it works but it can not send through my coding.

This is my function & give result as follows,
Result=

> "{"multicast_id":7523757847702384710,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1558857210405129%6298e0406298e040"}]}"

```
public function sendNotification(Request $req)
{
      $fcm_token=$req->input('fcm_token');
      $json_data=[
    "to" =>  $fcm_token,
    "notification" => [
        "body" => "hello",
        "title" => "hello"    
    ]

];

      $data = json_encode($json_data);
//FCM API end-point
$url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
//api_key in Firebase Console -> Project Settings -> CLOUD MESSAGING -> Server key
$server_key = 'AIzaSyDF4_rqij_Bt4zC3GNEVbNFvwX1HHxy5Mo';
//header with content_type api key
$headers = array(
    'Content-Type:application/json',
    'Authorization:key='.$server_key
);
//CURL request to route notification to FCM connection server (provided by Google)
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
if ($result === FALSE) {
    die('Oops! FCM Send Error: ' . curl_error($ch));
}
curl_close($ch);

dd($result);

}
```

When I send a notification, mobile gets the push notification.

Comment: on which device you are sending push notification, either on android or iOS?

Comment: i am using android

Comment: It works,but i want to send page name through notification@AsadChoudhary

Answer (score 1):

In laravel we usually use [brozot](https://packagist.org/packages/brozot/laravel-fcm) package to send push notification through laravel instead of using the core php.

https://packagist.org/packages/brozot/laravel-fcm